# On click function doesn't work on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to laravel and I want to print the result in console when I click on the "Edit" link in the below code.

```
<section class="row posts">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <header><h3>Others Opinions...</h3></header>
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <article class="post">
                    <p>
                        {{$post->body}}
                    </p>
                    <div class="info">
                        Posted by {{$post->user->email}} on {{$post->created_at}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="interaction">
                        <a href="#">Like</a> |
                        <a href="#">Dislike</a>
                        @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                            |
                            <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                            <a href="{{route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}">Delete</a>

                        @endif
                    </div>
                </article>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="modal fade" tableindex="-1" role="dialog" id="edit-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my js for resulting in console

```
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('a').eq(2).on('click', function(){
    console.log('yes');
});
```

But I don't get any message in my console. I tried following code too. But the result is same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post .interaction a:eq(2)').click(function() {
    console.log('yes');
  });
})
```

I've include the following scripts

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What is the reason that this code isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sonod the find interaction class result in many a tags maybe you should bind the post_id with the a tag and select that instead.

change your Edit  to id}}>Edit

and edit your js code to

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#post2').click(function() {
    console.log('yes');
  });
})
```

Comment: what this "id}}>Edit" means?

Comment: sorry it typo error i mean change it to this 
<a href="#" class="edit" id="post{{$post->id}}">Edit</a>

Comment: sorry it typo error i mean change it to this 
<a href="#" class="edit" id="post{{$post->id}}">Edit</a>

Comment: Nothing happens.Same problem

Answer (score 0):

As the edit button is in a loop. You need to use .each function.

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".post .interaction .edit").each(function(index) {
             $(this).on("click", function(){
                        console.log('yes');
                    });
              });
        });
```

Comment: still nothing.same problem